# How Do I fill the Area of a Polar Plot

Tags: manipulate

Grandson and I are working on the Calculus of Polar Coordinates, specifically, finding the area enclosed by a polar plot.  We can find the area; however, we cannot seem to find anything in the documentation that tells us how to fill the area when using PolarPlot.

The function we are working on is: r = a (1 - Sin[theta]).

Our code for the area is:

```
Integrate[(a/2) (1 - Sin[theta])^2, {theta, 0, 2 pi})
```

We used the following code to create a simple manipulate:

```
Manipulate[
line1 = PolarPlot[{ρ1 = (a/2) (1 - Sin[θ])^2}, {θ, 0, 
 2 π}, PolarGridLines -> Automatic,  PlotRange -> Automatic, 
PlotLabel -> "Polar Graph of the 
Cardiod: 
ρ1 = a (1 - Sin[θ]), (Blue)
with a varying from 1 to 10
Suggested value is a = 1
 "], {a, 1, 10}]
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can post-process `PolarPlot` output to add  [`FilledCurve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilledCurve.html)s:

```
PolarPlot[Evaluate @ Table[a (1 - Sin[θ]), {a, 10, 1, -1}], {θ, 0, 2 π}, 
  Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"] /. 
 l_Line :> {l, Dynamic[Lighter@Lighter@CurrentValue["Color"]], FilledCurve[l]}
```

[image]

```
pp = PolarPlot[5 (1 - Sin[θ])^2, {θ, 0, 2 π}, 
  PolarGridLines -> True, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> None]; 

Manipulate[Show[pp, PolarPlot[(a/2) (1 - Sin[θ])^2, {θ, 0, 2 π}] /. 
       l_Line -> {l, Opacity[.5], FilledCurve[l]}, 
     PlotLabel -> "Polar Graph of the Cardioid: " <> 
       ToString[a / 2 (1 - Sin[θ]) , TraditionalForm]],
  {a, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The second graph, showing polar coordinate lines is exactly what we were looking for!

Answer (score 4):

We can use `ParametricPlot` instead of `PolarPlot` to construct the region.
Here we change the definition of domain from `π/2` to `2 π + π/2` in order to make the boundary of region fine.

```
ρ[a_, θ_] := a (1 - Sin[θ]);
region = ParametricPlot[ρ[a, θ]*{Cos[θ], 
     Sin[θ]}, {θ, π/2, 2 π + π/2}, {a, 0, 
   2}, Axes -> False, BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Brown}, 
  PlotStyle -> Green, PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image]

Your animation maybe as this:

```
ρ[a_, θ_] := a (1 - Sin[θ]);
region[c_] := 
  ParametricPlot[{ρ[a, θ]*{Cos[θ], 
      Sin[θ]}}, {θ, π/2, 2 π + π/2}, {a, 0, 
    c}, Axes -> False, BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Brown}, 
   PlotStyle -> Green, PlotPoints -> 30, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];

Manipulate[{PolarPlot[10 (1 - Sin[θ]), {θ, 0, 2 π}, 
    PolarGridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> 20], region[a]} // 
  Show, {a, 1, 10}]
```