# How to fill a PolarPlot

Tags: plotting

I have a polar function like this how can I fill the closed area? Because I know for the `PolarPlot` can not use filing directly.

```
A=PolarPlot[0.5(7.89+8.12Cos[4t]+8.526(Sin[4t])^2), {t, Pi/4, 3Pi/4}]
```

Comment: `ParametricPlot`

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

{tmin, tmax} = 
 SolveValues[{(7.89 + 8.12 Cos[4 t] + 8.526 (Sin[4 t])^2) == 0, 
    Pi/4 < t < 3 Pi/4}, t, Reals] // Quiet

(* {0.819272, 2.32232} *)

Show[
 A = PolarPlot[
   0.5 (7.89 + 8.12 Cos[4 t] + 8.526 (Sin[4 t])^2), {t, tmin, tmax}],
 Graphics[{LightBlue, 
   Cases[A, Line[pts_] :> Polygon[pts], Infinity]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another way was suggested by [`@kglr`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/233676/how-do-i-fill-the-area-of-a-polar-plot/233681#233681) and it works in the following manner:

```
PolarPlot[
  0.5 (7.89 + 8.12 Cos[4 t] + 8.526 (Sin[4 t])^2), {t, Pi/4, 
   3 Pi/4}] /. 
 xx_Line :> {xx, Dynamic[Lighter@Lighter@CurrentValue["Color"]], 
   FilledCurve[xx]}
```

> [image: polar]